# Adding a filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new with angularjs and I am trying to create a filter that remove spaces from a string.

removeSpaces.js

```
angular.module('filters.stringUtils', [])
.filter('removeSpaces', [function() {
    return function(string) {
        if (!angular.isString(string)) {
            return string;
        }
        return string.replace(/[\s]/g, '');
    };
}])
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="ItemController">
<p ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="/items/{{ item.item_name | removeSpaces }}">{{ item.item_name }}</a>
</p>
```

itemcontroller.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ItemController', [
  '$scope', 'Services', '$http','removeSpaces', function($scope, Services, $http,removeSpaces) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    return $scope.services = Services.query();
  }
]);
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown provider: removeSpacesFilterProvider <- removeSpacesFilter
```

Comment: is the filter.stringUtils module noted in the dependencies of myApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app you have to use the module for you app.

So do this and it should work

```
angular.module('myApp', ['filters.stringUtils'])
```